# Proof of set being $\sigma$-finite

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I'm asked to prove:

"$f \in L^1(d\mu) \Rightarrow D= \{x:f(x) \neq0\}$ is $\sigma$-finite"

My approach is:

$f \in L^1(d\mu) \Rightarrow \displaystyle \int_X \mid{f}\mid\mu < \infty \Rightarrow \int_X {s}d\mu < \infty$ for every $s$ step function with $0\leq s(x)\leq \mid f(x)\mid$ $\forall x \in X$.

Let $A_n=\{x \in X: n <\mid f(x)\mid\leq n+1\}$. It is easy to see that $D=\cup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n$.

Then, $\forall n \geq 1$, we have $\displaystyle \int_X n\chi_{A_n}d\mu=\int_{A_n}nd\mu=n\mu(A_n)$. As $n\chi_{A_n}$ is a step function with the properties listed above, it follows that $\mu(A_n)<\infty$.

However, I do not know how to proceed with $A_0$, because $0\mu(A_0) = 0$ even if $\mu(A_0)=\infty$.

Comment: Use $$D_n = \{x \in X : \lvert f(x)\rvert > 1/n\}\,.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\{x~|~|f(x)|> 0\} = \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \{x~|~|f(x)|> 1/n\},$$
and each $\{x~|~|f(x)|> 1/n\}$ has a finite measure by Bienaymé-Tchebychev inequality
$$\mu(\{x~|~|f(x)|> a\}) = \frac{1}{a} \int_X |f(x)|~d\mu(x).$$